# Why i am not getting the current page url on ion_auth login

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I getting a problem while redirecting to the login page. Actually I am trying to implement the function to redirect back to the last page after login. For that, I am using sessions to store the current URL. Getting the current page URL on every page correctly and I have exempted the login page to store the URL. But when I am clicking the login button it gives me some asset URL(http://127.0.0.1/project/assets/images/favicons.png).

I am using the following code in CodeIgniter to store the url in session where current_url() function is the predefined function of Codeigniter to get the current page.

```
if (!$loggedin) {
$this->session->set_userdata('last_page_bbb12',current_url());
}
```

to get the URL using the following code

```
$last_page = $this->session->userdata('last_page_bbb12');
```

Comment: which CI version are you using?

Comment: Can you check your `current_url()` before adding it to session? See if you are inserting the right value?